# Loading user controls dynamically based on list of strings (Without code behind)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a project where the user should be able to export the values of different custom objects.

I am trying to find a way to load a number of check boxes dynamically (i am thinking user controls) based on a list of property names (string). The user should then be able to check or uncheck the check boxes based on the values that should be exported.

The problem I have is that I cannot give the user controls check boxes custom names which would link to the values that should be exported.

Comment: Post some pic of your requirement

Comment: `ItemsControl` usually used to load a number of controls dynamically based on a list

Comment: From the information you provided it seems like a use case for a ListBox/ItemsControl where the ItemTemplate renders a check box? But the question is a little too vague to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox` or `ItemsControl` (if you need more flexibility) are definitely the way to go. However, it's not going to be enough to just generate the `CheckBox`es as you're also going to need a way to track whether they're selected, so you want to make some kind of `Choice` class and bind the properties of the `CheckBox` to those of your `Choice` class. Something like this:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChosen}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And the code-behind:

```
public class Choice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChosen { get; set; }
}
```

Where your `Choices` property is a `List` or `IEnumerable` of `Choice`s.

Comment: Depending on the OP's needs, `Choice` may need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  In the most common scenario though, your code is perfect.